# django template filters: counting objects

Tags: django, templates, filter, count

I have 2 classes in models.py Region and Survey. Survey have `region_select=model.ForeignKey(region)` and some other attributes and region just have `name=models.CharField`. Using django generic views i make a list of items/region and i would like to have a filtered number of those items. My template looks like:

```
<..>
    <ul>
        {% for Region in regions_list  %}
            <p><b>{{ Region }}</b> <i>(count: {{ ??? }} )</i><br>
            {% for Survey in object_list  %}
                {% if Survey.region_select = Region %}
                    <a href="{% url region-display Region.id %}">{{ Survey }}</a>
                {% endif %}
            </p>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
<..>
```

region_list is queryset of `Region.objects.all()`
same with object list (`Survey.objects.all()`)
So far i get perfect list though i want to count those items separately for each region.
I've tried `object_list.filter(region_select=Region).count` but writing anything to filter ended up with template error saying that it could not parse what i give to filter. any suggestions what goes to `???` place? What about custom {{name|filter}} filters? again i just need that it would count objects... oh, i also tried adding method with same `Survey.objects.filter(region_select=Region).count` but it ended up writing a place and type of those objects(?!?).

P.S. its not copy/paste so simple mistakes may have occurred while re-writing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
Region.survey_set.all.count
```

Comment: I've seen _set in docs but will it make this automatically, i mean objectName_set part, because i thought it just is a way to tell that you're giving query set.

Comment: When you define `region_select=model.ForeignKey(Region)` in Survey model, django automatically add `survey_set` in Region model for you. `region.survey_set` is equal to `Survey.objects.filter(region_select=region)`. Of course you could use custom tag to accomplish similar function, but the model_set way is more djangoish. And btw, you could not use filter directly in template because template is only about displaying things and there should not be business logic in there.

Comment: Yes those reverse relationships are created automatically unless you override their names with the `related_name` argument.

Comment: so i'm adding 
    def get_count(self):
        return Region.Survey_set.all.count
it gives, empty value after calling {{ Region.get_count }} in ??? place

Comment: if i try to add attribute in region get_count = survey_set.all.count it says that survey_set is not defined

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear. You asked 'any suggestions what goes to ??? place?'. And my answer is to that question. Just put {{ Region.survey_set.all.count }} in your template and if you're lucky, you'll get what you want. BTW, if you want a new attribute in your model, try `return self.survey_set.all().count()

Comment: return self.survey_set.all().count() did the job so calling {{Region.get_count}} i get the wished numbers. Thanks, by the way you could edit the answer so others would find info faster rather than reading comments.